Pytorch : Early stopping Mechanism
I work with Pytorch and CIFAR100 dataset, While I'm newer, I would like to incorporate the early stopping mechanism in my code,
def train(net,trainloader,epochs,use_gpu = True): 
    ...
    net.train()
    for epoch in range(epochs):  
        print ("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch+1, epochs))
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_corrects = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            images, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item()
            
        epoch_loss = running_loss/len(trainloader.dataset)
        print('Loss: {}'.format(epoch_loss))  

This is the class of early stopping:
class EarlyStopper:
    def __init__(self, patience=1, min_delta=0):
        self.patience = patience
        self.min_delta = min_delta
        self.counter = 0
        self.min_validation_loss = float('inf')

    def early_stop(self, validation_loss):
        if validation_loss < self.min_validation_loss:
            self.min_validation_loss = validation_loss
            self.counter = 0
        elif validation_loss > (self.min_validation_loss + self.min_delta):
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter >= self.patience:
                return True
        return False

I don't have a validation set, I suppose that test set is same as validation set
Now, I would like to know where I must make those lines:
early_stopper = EarlyStopper(patience=3, min_delta=10)
for epoch in np.arange(n_epochs):
    train_loss = train_one_epoch(model, train_loader)
    validation_loss = validate_one_epoch(model, validation_loader)
    if early_stopper.early_stop(validation_loss):             
        break


Validation set is a subset of your dataset, that is not used for training. It requires having true labels for the samples though. If your test set is like that, then yes you can use it.
(Downside is that you cannot check that you didn't overfitted your hyperparameters to the test set.)
The early stopping mechanism as you copy/pasted from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73704579/20128192](this answer) is to be used inside the training loop of your model, which in pseudo code can look like this :
for epoch in num_epochs
    for sample, target in training_data:
       output = model(sample)
       loss = loss_function(output, target)
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       optimizer.zero_grad()
    for sample, target in {test or validation}_data:
       val_loss += loss_function(model(sample), target)
    val_loss /= len(validation_data)
    
    if early_stopper.early_stop(validation_loss):             
        break # this ends the outer for loop, effectively stopping the training

